# Pass javascript into a .txt file with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, shopping-cart

Ok so far I have had some help from you guys and this is the last thing that I have spent way too much time on.

I am using nopCart for an online store for uni. We aren't required to do the back end stuff but I have been saving the customer details to a text file. Inititally I was able to get everything sent via email but since going through PHP I don't know how to get the order details. The customer information is entered into text boxes and then saved to the text file via PHP.

My checkout code

```
        <form action="process.php" method ="post">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                CheckoutCart();
            </script>
            <br /><br />
            First Name:     <input type="text" name="first" /><br />
            Last Name:      <input type="text" name="last" /><br />
            Street Address: <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
            Suburb:         <input type="text" name="suburb" /><br />
            State:          <input type="text" name="state" /><br />
            Postcode:       <input type="text" name="postcode" /><br />
            Country:        <input type="text" name="country" /><br />
            Phone Number:   <input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
            Email:          <input type="text" name="email" /><br />

            shop:           <input type="text" name="shop" /><br />
            <br /><br />
            Other form data can go here when you create your prototype cart ...
            <br /><br />

            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value=" Submit Order " />
        </form>
```

Input shop is not currently being used, where I have trying to get the order information into

My process.php code

```
<?php
// We will put the data into a file in the current directory called "data.txt"
// But first of all, we need to check if the user actually pushed submit
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
// The user clicked submit
// Put the contents of the text into the file
file_put_contents('./data.txt', $_POST['shop'] . " " .$_POST['first'] . " " . $_POST['last'] . "\n" . $_POST['address'] . "\n" . $_POST['suburb'] . " " . $_POST['state'] . " " . $_POST['postcode'] . "\n" . $_POST['country'] . "\n" . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
// ./data.txt: the text file in which the data will be stored
// $_POST['myInputName']: What the user put in the form field named "myInputName"
// FILE_APPEND: This tells the function to append to the file and not to overwrite it.
}
?>
```

In an earlier version using this code in the checkout.html. This would email me everything i needed

```
<!-- Checkout Begin-->
            The items listed below are currently in your shopping cart:

            <form action="mailto:xxxxxxx@example.com" method ="post">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    CheckoutCart();
                </script>
                <br /><br />
                Name:   <input type="text" name="b_first" />
                        <input type="text" name="b_last" /><br />
                Email:  <input type="text" name="b_email" /><br />
                <br /><br />
                Other form data can go here when you create your prototype cart ...
                <br /><br />

                <input type="submit" value=" Submit Order " />
            </form>
            <!-- Checkout End -->
```

On clicking the send button I would get this text opening in a new email

ID_1=ID+000&QUANTITY_1=1&PRICE_1=28.99&NAME_1=Cat+Scratcher&SHIPPING_1=4.99&ADDTLINFO_1=&SUBTOTAL=%2428.99&SHIPPING=%244.99&TAX=%240.00&TOTAL=%2433.98&b_first=Jonny&b_last=Smith&b_email=a%40a.com

I would like to be able to get this string here into the .txt file with the customer details. Is there an easy way to get this information from CheckoutCart() and save it in a text box so I can then add it to my process.php and get it into the text file?

So far I have just been using trial and error and I'm really not sure what to do next

Here is the checkoutCart function from nopcart.js

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------||
// FUNCTION:    CheckoutCart                                           ||
// PARAMETERS:  Null                                                   ||
// RETURNS:     Product Table Written to Document                      ||
// PURPOSE:     Draws current cart product table on HTML page for      ||
//              checkout.                                              ||
//---------------------------------------------------------------------||
function CheckoutCart( ) {
   var iNumberOrdered = 0;    //Number of products ordered
   var fTotal         = 0;    //Total cost of order
   var fTax           = 0;    //Tax amount
   var fShipping      = 0;    //Shipping amount
   var strTotal       = "";   //Total cost formatted as money
   var strTax         = "";   //Total tax formatted as money
   var strShipping    = "";   //Total shipping formatted as money
   var strOutput      = "";   //String to be written to page
   var bDisplay       = true; //Whether to write string to the page (here for programmers)
   var strPP          = "";   //Payment Processor Description Field

   iNumberOrdered = GetCookie("NumberOrdered");
   if ( iNumberOrdered == null )
      iNumberOrdered = 0;

   if ( TaxByRegion ) {
      QueryString_Parse();
      fTax = parseFloat( QueryString( OutputOrderTax ) );
      strTax = moneyFormat(fTax);
   }

   if ( bDisplay )
      strOutput = "<TABLE CLASS=\"nopcart\"><TR>" +
                  "<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strILabel+"</B></TD>" +
                  "<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strDLabel+"</B></TD>" +
                  "<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strQLabel+"</B></TD>" +
                  "<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strPLabel+"</B></TD>" +
                  (DisplayShippingColumn?"<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strSLabel+"</B></TD>":"") +
                  "</TR>";

   for ( i = 1; i <= iNumberOrdered; i++ ) {
      NewOrder = "Order." + i;
      database = "";
      database = GetCookie(NewOrder);

      Token0 = database.indexOf("|", 0);
      Token1 = database.indexOf("|", Token0+1);
      Token2 = database.indexOf("|", Token1+1);
      Token3 = database.indexOf("|", Token2+1);
      Token4 = database.indexOf("|", Token3+1);

      fields = new Array;
      fields[0] = database.substring( 0, Token0 );                 // Product ID
      fields[1] = database.substring( Token0+1, Token1 );          // Quantity
      fields[2] = database.substring( Token1+1, Token2 );          // Price
      fields[3] = database.substring( Token2+1, Token3 );          // Product Name/Description
      fields[4] = database.substring( Token3+1, Token4 );          // Shipping Cost
      fields[5] = database.substring( Token4+1, database.length ); //Additional Information

      fTotal     += (parseInt(fields[1]) * parseFloat(fields[2]) );
      fShipping  += (parseInt(fields[1]) * parseFloat(fields[4]) );
      if ( !TaxByRegion ) fTax = (fTotal * TaxRate);
      strTotal    = moneyFormat(fTotal);
      if ( !TaxByRegion ) strTax = moneyFormat(fTax);
      strShipping = moneyFormat(fShipping);

      if ( bDisplay ) {
         strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"  + fields[0] + "</TD>";

         if ( fields[5] == "" )
            strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"  + fields[3] + "</TD>";
         else
            strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"  + fields[3] + " - <I>"+ fields[5] + "</I></TD>";

         strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">" + fields[1] + "</TD>";
         strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"+ MonetarySymbol + moneyFormat(fields[2]) + "/ea</TD>";

         if ( DisplayShippingColumn ) {
            if ( parseFloat(fields[4]) > 0 )
               strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"+ MonetarySymbol + moneyFormat(fields[4]) + "/ea</TD>";
            else
               strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">N/A</TD>";
         }

         strOutput += "</TR>";
      }

      if ( AppendItemNumToOutput ) {
         strFooter = i;
      } else {
         strFooter = "";
      }
      if ( PaymentProcessor != '' ) {
         //Process description field for payment processors instead of hidden values.
         //Format Description of product as:
         // ID, Name, Qty X
         strPP += fields[0] + ", " + fields[3];
         if ( fields[5] != "" )
            strPP += " - " + fields[5];
         strPP += ", Qty. " + fields[1] + "\n";
      } else {
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemId        + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[0] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemQuantity  + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[1] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemPrice     + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[2] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemName      + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[3] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemShipping  + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[4] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemAddtlInfo + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[5] + "\">";
      } 

   }

   if ( bDisplay ) {
      strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strSUB+"</B></TD>";
      strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + strTotal + "</B></TD>";
      strOutput += "</TR>";

      if ( DisplayShippingRow ) {
         strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strSHIP+"</B></TD>";
         strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + strShipping + "</B></TD>";
         strOutput += "</TR>";
      }

      if ( DisplayTaxRow || TaxByRegion ) {
         strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strTAX+"</B></TD>";
         strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + strTax + "</B></TD>";
         strOutput += "</TR>";
      }

      strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strTOT+"</B></TD>";
      strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "</B></TD>";
      strOutput += "</TR>";

      strOutput += "</TABLE>";


      if ( PaymentProcessor == 'an') {
         //Process this for Authorize.net WebConnect
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"x_Version\" value=\"3.0\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"x_Show_Form\" value=\"PAYMENT_FORM\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"x_Description\" value=\""+ strPP + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"x_Amount\" value=\""+ moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "\">";
      } else if ( PaymentProcessor == 'wp') {
         //Process this for WorldPay
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"desc\" value=\""+ strPP + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"amount\" value=\""+ moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "\">";
      } else if ( PaymentProcessor == 'lp') {
         //Process this for LinkPoint         
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"mode\" value=\"fullpay\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"chargetotal\" value=\""+ moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"tax\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strTax + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"subtotal\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strTotal + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"shipping\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strShipping + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"desc\" value=\""+ strPP + "\">";
      } else {
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\""+OutputOrderSubtotal+"\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strTotal + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\""+OutputOrderShipping+"\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strShipping + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\""+OutputOrderTax+"\"      value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strTax + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\""+OutputOrderTotal+"\"    value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "\">";
      }
   }

   document.write(strOutput);
   document.close();
}

//=====================================================================||
//               END NOP Design SmartPost Shopping Cart                ||
//=====================================================================||
```

I know it's a lot of text and code but I don't think it will be too hard to find a solution, it is only the first in depth HTML subject in my course and I am hoping to get this working.

Comment: People still use Hungarian Notation?

Comment: @crush the shopping cart was given to us to use. It is VERY old

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
file_put_contents('data.txt', var_export($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

That would save all fields in the $_POST parameter to the file.

An alternatives to var_export($_POST, true) is json_encode($_POST) which can be read by Javascript later, or you can format some human readable text instead.

For example put this in your `process.php`.

```
<?php
// submitButton was sent.
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
    // Build a string with all fields that was submitted.

    $str = "--- BEGIN ORDER ---\n"
    // For each field in the $_POST variable, iterate and add them to the string.
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
        $str .= "$k: $v\n";
    }
    $str .= "--- END ORDER ---\n";

    // Show the user the result
    echo $str;

    // Also save it to data.txt
    file_put_contents('data.txt', $str, FILE_APPEND);
} else {
    // submitButton was not sent, show some error.
    echo "Please submit something";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am getting an error with this part var_strOutput($_POST, true),

Comment: I have put it in the process.php file but I am getting
Fatal error: Call to undefined function CheckoutCart() in /home/stud/s3163744/.HTMLinfo/Pets/process.php on line 25

If the function is in nopcart.js and I have  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src ="js/nopcart.js"></script> at the top of my process.php file what am I missing?

Comment: CheckoutCart() is javascript and is executed by the browser. The PHP code is executed by the server. Therefore the javascript cannot be executed on the server side. If use the code for `process.php` as you wrote it in your question and replaces the `file_put_contents` line with the one I suggested, It should write all variables that was send to the server from the form.