# javascript for loop to get order details

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I want to put a for loop in this nopcart.js file so that I can save the details of the order as a string. At the moment it is outputting all the details of the order into a table to display of the checkout page. I just want the array information

```
fields = new Array;
          fields[0] = database.substring( 0, Token0 );                 // Product ID
          fields[1] = database.substring( Token0+1, Token1 );          // Quantity
          fields[2] = database.substring( Token1+1, Token2 );          // Price
          fields[3] = database.substring( Token2+1, Token3 );          // Product Name/Description
          fields[4] = database.substring( Token3+1, Token4 );          // Shipping Cost
          fields[5] = database.substring( Token4+1, database.length ); //Additional Information
```

to loop and save into one string. Then have all the order details on one string which I can then save to a text file in php. (We are not using SQL at the moment.

So far my attempts have only gotten the last item in the cart, or the loop is also writing the html table code as well. This is for a uni assignment and we were not meant to edit the basic shopping cart functions but I think it will be much more useful saving the customer and order details to a text file.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------||
// FUNCTION:    CheckoutCart                                           ||
// PARAMETERS:  Null                                                   ||
// RETURNS:     Product Table Written to Document                      ||
// PURPOSE:     Draws current cart product table on HTML page for      ||
//              checkout.                                              ||
//---------------------------------------------------------------------||
function CheckoutCart( ) {
   var iNumberOrdered = 0;    //Number of products ordered
   var fTotal         = 0;    //Total cost of order
   var fTax           = 0;    //Tax amount
   var fShipping      = 0;    //Shipping amount
   var strTotal       = "";   //Total cost formatted as money
   var strTax         = "";   //Total tax formatted as money
   var strShipping    = "";   //Total shipping formatted as money
   var strOutput      = "";   //String to be written to page
   var bDisplay       = true; //Whether to write string to the page (here for programmers)
   var strPP          = "";   //Payment Processor Description Field

   iNumberOrdered = GetCookie("NumberOrdered");
   if ( iNumberOrdered == null )
      iNumberOrdered = 0;

   if ( TaxByRegion ) {
      QueryString_Parse();
      fTax = parseFloat( QueryString( OutputOrderTax ) );
      strTax = moneyFormat(fTax);
   }

   if ( bDisplay )
      strOutput = "<TABLE CLASS=\"nopcart\"><TR>" +
                  "<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strILabel+"</B></TD>" +
                  "<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strDLabel+"</B></TD>" +
                  "<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strQLabel+"</B></TD>" +
                  "<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strPLabel+"</B></TD>" +
                  (DisplayShippingColumn?"<TD CLASS=\"nopheader\"><B>"+strSLabel+"</B></TD>":"") +
                  "</TR>";

   for ( i = 1; i <= iNumberOrdered; i++ ) {
      NewOrder = "Order." + i;
      database = "";
      database = GetCookie(NewOrder);

      Token0 = database.indexOf("|", 0);
      Token1 = database.indexOf("|", Token0+1);
      Token2 = database.indexOf("|", Token1+1);
      Token3 = database.indexOf("|", Token2+1);
      Token4 = database.indexOf("|", Token3+1);

      fields = new Array;
      fields[0] = database.substring( 0, Token0 );                 // Product ID
      fields[1] = database.substring( Token0+1, Token1 );          // Quantity
      fields[2] = database.substring( Token1+1, Token2 );          // Price
      fields[3] = database.substring( Token2+1, Token3 );          // Product Name/Description
      fields[4] = database.substring( Token3+1, Token4 );          // Shipping Cost
      fields[5] = database.substring( Token4+1, database.length ); //Additional Information



      fTotal     += (parseInt(fields[1]) * parseFloat(fields[2]) );
      fShipping  += (parseInt(fields[1]) * parseFloat(fields[4]) );
      if ( !TaxByRegion ) fTax = (fTotal * TaxRate);
      strTotal    = moneyFormat(fTotal);
      if ( !TaxByRegion ) strTax = moneyFormat(fTax);
      strShipping = moneyFormat(fShipping);

      if ( bDisplay ) {
         strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"  + fields[0] + "</TD>";

         if ( fields[5] == "" )
            strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"  + fields[3] + "</TD>";
         else
            strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"  + fields[3] + " - <I>"+ fields[5] + "</I></TD>";

         strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">" + fields[1] + "</TD>";
         strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"+ MonetarySymbol + moneyFormat(fields[2]) + "/ea</TD>";

         if ( DisplayShippingColumn ) {
            if ( parseFloat(fields[4]) > 0 )
               strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">"+ MonetarySymbol + moneyFormat(fields[4]) + "/ea</TD>";
            else
               strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"nopentry\">N/A</TD>";
         }

         strOutput += "</TR>";
      }

      if ( AppendItemNumToOutput ) {
         strFooter = i;
      } else {
         strFooter = "";
      }
      if ( PaymentProcessor != '' ) {
         //Process description field for payment processors instead of hidden values.
         //Format Description of product as:
         // ID, Name, Qty X
         strPP += fields[0] + ", " + fields[3];
         if ( fields[5] != "" )
            strPP += " - " + fields[5];
         strPP += ", Qty. " + fields[1] + "\n";
      } else {
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemId        + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[0] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemQuantity  + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[1] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemPrice     + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[2] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemName      + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[3] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemShipping  + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[4] + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"" + OutputItemAddtlInfo + strFooter + "\" value=\"" + fields[5] + "\">";

      } 

   }

   if ( bDisplay ) {
      strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strSUB+"</B></TD>";
      strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + strTotal + "</B></TD>";
      strOutput += "</TR>";

      if ( DisplayShippingRow ) {
         strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strSHIP+"</B></TD>";
         strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + strShipping + "</B></TD>";
         strOutput += "</TR>";
      }

      if ( DisplayTaxRow || TaxByRegion ) {
         strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strTAX+"</B></TD>";
         strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + strTax + "</B></TD>";
         strOutput += "</TR>";
      }

      strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strTOT+"</B></TD>";
      strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "</B></TD>";
      strOutput += "</TR>";

      strOutput += "</TABLE>";


      if ( PaymentProcessor == 'an') {
         //Process this for Authorize.net WebConnect
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"x_Version\" value=\"3.0\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"x_Show_Form\" value=\"PAYMENT_FORM\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"x_Description\" value=\""+ strPP + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"x_Amount\" value=\""+ moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "\">";
      } else if ( PaymentProcessor == 'wp') {
         //Process this for WorldPay
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"desc\" value=\""+ strPP + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"amount\" value=\""+ moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "\">";
      } else if ( PaymentProcessor == 'lp') {
         //Process this for LinkPoint         
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"mode\" value=\"fullpay\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"chargetotal\" value=\""+ moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"tax\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strTax + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"subtotal\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strTotal + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"shipping\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strShipping + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\"desc\" value=\""+ strPP + "\">";
      } else {
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\""+OutputOrderSubtotal+"\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strTotal + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\""+OutputOrderShipping+"\" value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strShipping + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\""+OutputOrderTax+"\"      value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + strTax + "\">";
         strOutput += "<input type=hidden name=\""+OutputOrderTotal+"\"    value=\""+ MonetarySymbol + moneyFormat((fTotal + fShipping + fTax)) + "\">";
      }
   }

   document.write(strOutput);


   document.close();
}
```

Thanks guys for your help, you have already helped me out a fair bit already. I can't wait until I'm much more familiar with programming and can figure this stuff out instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

Based on our discussion, is this the code you're looking for (or something like it)?

```
// Return a string containing all of the items in the cart,
// one line per item with a newline character after each line,
// and the fields in each line separated by | characters.
function getCartString() {
    var result = '',
        count = GetCookie('NumberOrdered') || 0;
    for( var i = 1;  i <= count;  i++ ) {
        result += GetCookie( 'Order.' + i ) + '\n';
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there anything in this code you don't understand? I'll be happy to explain it. And is the format it produces what you're looking for? If it isn't, describe the format you want in detail, and it should be trivial to generate it - now that the awful code from that `nopcart.js` fine is gone so it can't confuse us all.

#### Original answer

You're writing way too much code! It's very hard to follow, and very error-prone, when you have so much repetition.

**Edit:** The joke was on me! This isn't code you wrote, and it isn't code your professor or anyone like that wrote, it's some horrible script left over from the "Dynamic HTML" days. Still, the following may have a useful tip or two for anyone who does have to deal with a script like this. :-)

The most important thing for you to concentrate on right now is how to simplify your code. Two areas in particular stand out:

1. Use built-in JavaScript features instead of manual coding when you can.
2. Whenever you find yourself repeating a block of code, make it into a function.

Here's one example:

```
database = "";
database = GetCookie(NewOrder);

Token0 = database.indexOf("|", 0);
Token1 = database.indexOf("|", Token0+1);
Token2 = database.indexOf("|", Token1+1);
Token3 = database.indexOf("|", Token2+1);
Token4 = database.indexOf("|", Token3+1);

fields = new Array;
fields[0] = database.substring( 0, Token0 );                 // Product ID
fields[1] = database.substring( Token0+1, Token1 );          // Quantity
fields[2] = database.substring( Token1+1, Token2 );          // Price
fields[3] = database.substring( Token2+1, Token3 );          // Product Name/Description
fields[4] = database.substring( Token3+1, Token4 );          // Shipping Cost
fields[5] = database.substring( Token4+1, database.length ); //Additional Information
```

That code can be replaced with:

```
var database = GetCookie(NewOrder);
var fields = database.split('|');
```

Yes, really! This does exactly the same thing. (Well, not quite exactly. As you can see, it doesn't create all the `Token0`, `Token1`, etc. variables, but those aren't used anywhere else anyway.)

Also, instead of all the comments describing what `fields[0]`, `fields[1]`, etc. mean, you should *remove* those comments entirely and instead create named variables for all those fields:

```
var database = GetCookie(NewOrder);
var fields = database.split('|'),
    productID = fields[0],
    quantity = parseInt( fields[1], 10 ),
    price = +fields[2],
    description = fields[3],
    shipping = +fields[4],
    moreInfo = fields[5];
```

And then in the rest of your code, you can replace all the `fields[n]` references with those names. For example, this code:

```
 fTotal += ( parseInt(fields[1]) * parseFloat(fields[2]) );
```

can be replaced by:

```
 fTotal += quantity * price;
```

A little more readable that way, isn't it?

Related notes:

1. If you use `parseInt()`, *always* provide an explicit base in the second parameter. Otherwise if a user happens to enter "010" it will be converted to `8` which is probably not what's expected.
2. You can use `+someString` instead of `parseFloat(someString)` for simplicity.

And now something that I'll leave as an exercise for you. See all the places where you have code like this repeated several times with minor variations:

```
strOutput += "<TR><TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=3><B>"+strSUB+"</B></TD>";
strOutput += "<TD CLASS=\"noptotal\" COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=RIGHT><B>" + MonetarySymbol + strTotal + "</B></TD>";
strOutput += "</TR>";
```

Can you think of a way you could write that code *once* and call it multiple times, passing in the items that change for each instance? For example in the repetitions of this code, it's the same each time except for the place where you put in `strSUB` and `Symbol + strTotal`. The next place the code is repeated, it has `strSHIP` and `MonetarySymbol + strShipping` in those places but is identical otherwise. And so on.

Is there a way in JavaScript to write a reusable piece of code where you can pass in parameters like this, so the bulk of the code only appears once and you give it the parameters for each individual instance?

Finally, a minor stylistic note. Some of your HTML has `<lowercasetags>` and some has `<UPPERCASETAGS>`. The browser treats these identically regardless of case, but it's better to be consistent, and modern JavaScript/HTML code uses `<lowercasetags>`.

Comment: Thanks for your very in depth response! The nopcart.js was given to us to use and I am only modifying it now to get the order details into a string to save. I will have a go at this now and see how I go, I understand that your way is much easier to read but I am a little hesitant modifying this code without knowing an awful lot about javascript yet and making a mistake.

Comment: Ah, you didn't write this code, it was given to you to modify as part of an assignment? Then please forgive me for saying "You're writing way too much code!" and such things. But did your *professor* write this code? Then I'll take the gloves off: this person does not know how to code, and you should be very wary of learning things from them. But you are definitely right, when given a piece of hopelessly messy code that you have to modify, it's best to tread very carefully! At the very least, though, you might try that `.split('|')` code instead of the more lengthy version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the nopcart code is from 2005... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837915/pass-javascript-into-a-txt-file-with-php) I tried to explain what I wanted but not sure if I explained myself well enough. I thought saving the array as a string might work better for me

Comment: I see... I thought this was some code a professor handed out as part of an assignment. That was a scary thought! The good news is that you will end up throwing out almost all of the code in this function - like all of the HTML string concatenation. But here's what I don't understand: after you call `var database = GetCookie(NewOrder);`, you *already* have all the data in a string, the `database` variable. Why don't you throw out all the rest of the code and just use this string?

Comment: In fact, here's what you ought to do: forget about code entirely and just describe the data. Specify exactly what data you're getting and what data you want to produce - exactly what it looks like. Then the code will be simple to figure out. Until then we're just guessing.

Comment: Yes I think everything I want is in the cookie, so would document.write(Database); at the very end of the code display it?

Comment: No, you don't want `document.write` at all. I thought you wanted to send the resulting data back to your server with an Ajax call or the like? That won't involve `document.write`. Anyway, take this a step at a time: (1) generate the data you want - see my updated answer for one idea, and (2) send that data to your server. Don't try to think about both those problems at once, that's too confusing.

Comment: Thank you! sorry I was just using write to see that it was appearing. We haven't used SQL yet so I am just writing the order details to a text file.

Comment: Ah, very good. Pro tip: Instead of using `document.write()` to debug your code, use `console.log()` or the `debugger` statement and look at your variables in the JavaScript debugger. The one in Chrome is excellent; [here's an introduction](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help, I have literally been working on this for the last 5 hours.
Lastly, would you possibly know the best way to put this into a text file in php?

It works fine when putting the address in from a text box, but not sure the best way for the function
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
file_put_contents('./data.txt', getCartString($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);
}
?>

Comment: Gosh, I'm sorry, I hardly know PHP, but are you mixing up PHP and JavaScript code there? The `getCartString()` function is JavaScript code; you wouldn't be using it directly from PHP. Instead, you would have some other JavaScript code that takes that string and sends it to your server with a POST, and then code on your server receives that as the POST data and handles it from there. For the JavaScript part you could use jQuery's `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` function.

Comment: Yeah I've looking at different ways, the above method I read online but I don't think it is correct. At least I have the function working, this is just the last little step. Thanks again for your help